# Reading multiple lines from text file based on the starting prefix as record and then process it

Tags: java

I have text file as below

```
6200MIGS Draft Capture              001527160719256                                                                                                                                                                                                             
622001004987654321098769    2030000000002385250000000000000000000000000719024031629498071912403119100719301201208620112629498      00QFCBA003353109297315583010   036000000190 100         000000    SHOEBRIDGE/DANIEL T MR       VI50 0818950138744  600110190 
6221QANTAS AIR                                                         AUSTRALIA       036             T                                                                                                                                                        
6223       0000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
6229SHOEBRIDGE/DANIEL T MR                           0818950138744  QF  YNOGVJ                           15022602300045                                        -00000238525000000000000000000000000005                                                          
62301702281700BNE            MEL  QF  H XHLFEU           631                                000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                
62311702282335MEL            DXB  QF  H XHLFEU             9                                000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                
62321703011450DXB            LYS  QF  H OHLFEU          8081                                000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                
62331703082115CDG            DXB  QF  O XOLREU1         8076 0818950138745                  000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                
62341703091025DXB            BNE  QF  O  OLREU1         8434 0818950138745                  000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                
622001005123456789012346    2030000000000575650000000000000000000000000719024031629499071912403117080719301201208620112629499      00QFCBA003353109297315583000   036000000190 100         000000    DETTMAN/GLEN MR              CA50 0818950138719  600110190 
6221QANTAS AIR                                                         AUSTRALIA       036             T                                                                                                                                                        
6222         0719           000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
6229DETTMAN/GLEN MR                                  0818950138719  QF  YYUGBM                           15022602300045                                        -00000057565000000000000000000000000002                                                          
62301703151800MEL            SYD  QF  L OLPTSCN01        458                                000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                
62311703251830SYD            MEL  QF  M  MPTSCN01        463                                000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I want to read all lines starting with 6220 to the next 6220  in my case the lines are 2- 9 which i will call as a record. then i want to process each each line in the record based on the starting prefix for example if it starts with 6223 i will extract data what i need.
my question is how can i read the lines as record and then process it individually.

will mark and reset will be helpful .thanks in advance.The code which i have so far is

```
    File infile = new File("C:\\Data\\Everyday work\\tmp\\CBRF.GEN4_FILE.20160719.txt");
    File outfile = new File("C:\\Data\\Everyday work\\tmp\\CBRF.GEN4_FILE.20160719.txt-DCFOUT.txt");
    FileReader reader;
    Scanner scanner;
    public void output() {

        try {

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outfile);
            reader = new FileReader(infile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String str;
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            bw.flush();     
            while ((str = br.readLine() )!= null) {


                 scanner = new Scanner(str);

                String line = scanner.nextLine();
              if (line.startsWith("6220", 0)) {

                    recordtype = line.substring(0, 4);
                    msgrtypId = line.substring(4, 8);

                }     
          }   
   }
```

here i can read line by line what i am trying to achieve is to read lines between line prefix 6220 and the next line prefix 6220 as a record.

Comment: Well, you would start with writing code that reads strings from a text file. Or what exactly is your question?

Comment: You start by opening the file and reading it line-by-line using `BufferedReader`. Or simpler than that: You start by writing some code. *Then*, if you get stumped, you show us the code you have, and a description of the *specific* problem you have with the code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a code-writing request with no attempt made by the question author.

Comment: I have written  code to read text file line by line .my question is how can read all the lines from line starting prefix 6220 to next line of 6220 as record.

Comment: @Andreas i have code to read text file line by line but dont know to read lines as record

Comment: @GhostCat i have code to read the text file my question is how to read all the lines between starting with prefix 6220 to the next line starting with 6220. and process the lines as one record

Comment: Hint: you expect us to hep you. So you please spend some time and format your code in a decent manner. You know, "edit" has a preview function that you can use to make sure that you are not posting messy stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving problems is typically about creating helpful abstractions. You are still at a point where you suppose you have to things "low level": your code reads a line from a file; and right there, you start processing it.

So, lets step back and try to get on "higher ground":

First of all, do all "interesting" lines start with 6220? Or is the point that these lines have a specific format; that tells you that a new record begins? You see, that is very important; because if the later is true, you dont look for lines starting with 6220; but for lines that have the format of "record begins here" resp. "record ends here".

The next question is: what should happen to **other** lines?! Should they be ignored; or do you have to do other processing?

Then: is memory a constraint here? Meaning: would it be a good idea to simply read the complete file; and keep it in memory before doing any processing? Or is this a really large file; so large, that within your environment you should better not read the whole thing into memory?

You see, your question is lacking all this information; and seriously: things would get out of proportion if you tried to address all of that i a single question (or answer that is).

But let me give you some code to get started.

```
// before your loop starts
boolean currentlyParsingRecord = false;
boolean List<String> rawRecordLines = new ArrayList<>();

// within your loop
String line = scanner.nextLine();
if (currentlyParsingRecord) {
  if (line.startsWith("6220)) { 
    currentlyParsingRecord = false;
  }
  rawRecordLines.add(line);
} else {
  if (line.startsWith("6220)) { 
    currentlyParsingRecord = true;
    rawRecordLines.add(line);
    // and now, maybe you are calling a method like
    processRecordLines(rawRecordLines);
    // and then you clear your "buffer"
    rawRecordLines.clear();
  }
}
```

The point is: you have to somehow **collect** the lines that belong together. I am using a simple list here; and then you just pass that list around in order to process the data for that one record (and of course; you shouldn't forget about clearing that "buffer"; as you might start collecting the next one). Please note: of course this is not the final solution; it should only give you an idea how to go on from here. Such things can actually be pretty complicated to get right. And, you see; actually that is still a very "low-level" implementation; so there is a lot of room for improvement "OO design wise".

Hope that helps. But as said: before you further engage in programming; you better clarify your **requirements**. You should sit down; and talk to the people around you; to really understand how/what to process within that file. If you don't do that; chances are pretty high that whatever you will implement today won't be good enough any more tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the code i will work on it. for your questions I think the way i framed the question is confusing i will try my best to make it clear.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you to get to your goal.

Comment: I have achieved my goal using your code as base., Thank you very much for throwing the idea. I have accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can read the lines with a Reader and filter them with a lambda, like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, encoding));
return reader.lines().filter(line -> line.startsWith("6220 ")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then process the list of lines accordingly.